# Displaying loading gif within html object

Tags: javascript, html

I have a main page with a number of buttons. When a button is pressed the target page is loaded as an object within a div on this main page where **target** is the page to be displayed within the object.

```
<script>
    .... check which button is pressed and assign path to target 
    var objectContent = "<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"" + target + "\" height=\"500px\" width=\"100%\" style=\"overflow:auto; min-height:400px;\"></object>";
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = objectContent;
</script>
```

html

```
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

All works and the target page loads fine within the main page div.

Sometimes it can take a while to load the content and so I would make use of a loading gif. I have been using one on whole pages but I would like one just on the content within the div.

In a target page I have the following to display the loader:

```
<script>
    $(".loader").fadeIn("fast");
</script>
```

and this to hide it once the page is loaded

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loader").hide();
    });
</script>
```

This is not working. The page loads fine but no loading gif. No errors.

If I debug in the browser I see the gif as I step through so it must be loading and hiding, but not when I load the page normally. I suspect it is loading too late or hiding too soon.

Does my javascript show the loader as soon as the page starts to load? I have placed it at the beginning of the body.

Or is something I am doing to hide it before the page is fully loaded? Either way, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE AND ANSWER

Add the onload to the object tag as follows:

```
var out = "<object ... onload=\"contentLoaded(this)\"></object>";

<script>
    function contentLoaded() {
        $(".loader").hide();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You know sometimes browsers act strangely. The image may refuse to show up and its mostly caused when too much javascript code slows down the page and this happens often in Firefox and opera. Try using different other browsers

Comment: Thanks- it appears to behave the same in all browsers I have used.

Answer (score 1):

Then why not leave the `.loader` element empty and do something like this

```
$('.loader').fadeIn('fast').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
```

And this

```
$('.loader').hide().html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the trigger for the loading gif showing only within the loaded-in page?

If so, by the time the browser receives the instruction to show the loader, it's already fetched the data.

I imagine the majority of the time is spent waiting for the content so try showing the loader just before this happens:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = objectContent;
```

You could always create a localised loader image, set within the innerHTML, as you said you had a global one already.

Comment: The $(".loader").fadeIn("fast"); script is straight after the <body> tag - it is exactly as I have it here. The fade out script is just before the </body> tag. So when you say 'try showing the loader just before this happens' this is what I am trying to work out. The document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = objectContent; line is in the main page - not the target.

Comment: It needs to be on the containing/ host page, not the content you load in. Check your browser's network tab for the timings as to why you need to do it that way around.

Comment: That is fine and I can do that but how do I know when the object has completed loading?

Comment: The html being loaded in can hide the loader as it currently is :)

Comment: But how? That requires the loading page to talk to the host page.

Comment: Does the loaded page load from the same domain as the host page? If so, `parent.$(".loader").hide();`

Comment: Actually I have sussed it out. I will post an answer. Thanks for your time.